# How to get more than default 10 results from Wikipedia API?

Tags: wikipedia-api

I am using Wikipedia API where I get the images of certain string I input.
It always returns 10 result but I want more than that approx 50.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&format=json&piprop=thumbnail&pithumbsize=500&pilimit=50&generator=prefixsearch&gpssearch=game of thrones
```

How do I get 50 results?

Comment: According to the [API description](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php), exactly how you tried it. Apparently the API is broken or the documentation out of date. I recreaded your query in the [API Sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&prop=pageimages&generator=prefixsearch&pithumbsize=500&pilimit=50&gpssearch=test) but that doesn't work either.

Comment: It works on sandbox perfectly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved also need to add

```
&gpslimit=100
```

[image]
it should be in the range 1-100

Answer (score 1):

By default most of the **generator**s and **prop**s used in [query](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query) action are with limit of 10. Always when you need to increase the limit for your query you have to set the corresponding limit value for all them, because the resulting query limit is equal to smallest of all them.

So, if your query uses `generator=geosearch` with `prop=links|extracts|categories|images` and you need 20 results, you must set the limit parameters for `geosearch`, `links`, `extracts`, `categories` and `images` to 20.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?...&ggslimit=20&pllimit=20&exlimit=20&cllimit=20&imlimit=20
```

Of course this has to comply with the allowed max limit for each parameter. For example, for extracts the allowed max limit is 20 (default: 1), which means that you can't get more than 20 pages in your final response, although others are more than 20. This also means that in your case above the effect of `gpslimit=100` will be the same as `gpslimit=50`, because `pilimit=50`.